# Github action modify .env file

Tags: php, laravel, github-actions

I'm trying to setup a cicd pipeline using github actions for laravel and elasticbeanstalk. The part that confuses me is the .env file. Right now I have a workflow that runs the test, builds the project and deploy to eb in a zip file. It works but the .env file confuses me.

I have stored the rds credentials on github secrets and since we don't want the .env file to be on the repo so the logical thing to do is create the env file before deploying the zip.

How do I change only certain parts of the env variables. I'm already clonning the env.example for the test in the first place? The code below overrides the env.example file and creates a new one with only a few variables.

```
name: CI-CD-Production
on:
  workflow_dispatch:
  push:
    branches: [ "master" ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ "master" ]
jobs:
  building:
    name: 'Production: Build & Deploy App'
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    continue-on-error: false
    steps:
    - uses: shivammathur/setup-php@15c43e89cdef867065b0213be354c2841860869e
      with:
        php-version: '8.0'
    - uses: actions/checkout@v3
    - name: Copy .env
      run: php -r "file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');"
    - name: Install Dependencies
      run: composer install -q --no-ansi --no-interaction --no-scripts --no-progress --prefer-dist
    - name: Generate key
      run: php artisan key:generate
    - name: Install Packages
      run: npm install && npm run build
    - name: Directory Permissions
      run: chmod -R 777 storage bootstrap/cache
    - name: Create Database
      run: |
        mkdir -p database
        touch database/database.sqlite
    - name: Execute tests (Unit and Feature tests) via PHPUnit
      env:
        DB_CONNECTION: sqlite
        DB_DATABASE: database/database.sqlite
      run: vendor/bin/phpunit
    - name: Configure .env
      uses: SpicyPizza/create-envfile@v1.3
      with:
        envkey_DB_HOST: ${{ secrets.DB_HOST }}
        envkey_DB_DATABASE: ${{ secrets.DB_DATABASE}}
        envkey_DB_USERNAME: ${{ secrets.DB_USERNAME }}
        envkey_DB_PASSWORD: ${{ secrets.DB_PASSWORD }}
    - name: Generate deployment package
      run: zip -r deploy-${{ github.sha }}.zip . -x '*.git*'
    - name: Deploy to ElasticBeanstalk
      uses: einaregilsson/beanstalk-deploy@v20
      with:
        region: ap-southeast-1
        aws_access_key: ${{ secrets.ACCESS_KEY_ID }}
        aws_secret_key: ${{ secrets.SECRET_ACCESS_KEY }}
        application_name: application
        environment_name: application-env
        version_label: "ver-${{ github.sha }}"
        deployment_package: deploy-${{ github.sha }}.zip
        use_existing_version_if_available : true
```

Comment: you can store all the variables on github secrets .env file should never be taken into account unless ur local.

Comment: @jmvcollaborator thats kinda like stating the obvious right. I'm already doing it now.

Comment: Can you set `APP_ENV` in your action and create a `.env.[APP_ENV]` that can actually checked into source control? https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/configuration#additional-environment-files

Comment: @ChrisHaas ya, the problem im having now is, how do u modify the existing .env file with linux command i guess

Comment: I’m unfortunately not as familiar with Laravel. In Symfony we put our base stuff in` .env` files and actually commit that file. We then use `.env.local` or `.env.test` or even `.env.test.local` which inherit and override the base file. Not much help to you, I’m sorry, but after reading the Laravel docs closer it appears the inheritance isn’t a part of that.